# Error 500 devolviendo array por json ajax

Tags: php, ajax, json

Estoy tratando de devolver un `array` mediante `json` pero cuando realiza la petición, el `AJAX` devuelve error 500. Si ejecuto el `php` e imprimo el `array`, este esta correctamente.

```
    <?php 
$idioma_seleccionado = "en";


$array_traducciones = array();

$datos = array();

$traducciones = $mysqli->query("SELECT identrada, entrada_padre
                             FROM entradas
                             WHERE entrada_padre != 0
                             AND idioma = '$idioma_seleccionado'
                             ORDER BY identrada
                             ");


if (mysqli_num_rows($traducciones) > 0){


    while($r = $traducciones->fetch_object()){

        array_push($array_traducciones, $r->entrada_padre);

    }

    $query = $db->query("SELECT identrada, titulo FROM entradas WHERE entrada_padre = 0");

    if($query->num_rows > 0){
        //recorremos el resultado de la consulta
        while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){

            $entrada['identrada'] = $row['identrada'];
            $entrada['titulo'] = $row['titulo'];

            if (!in_array($row['identrada'], $array_traducciones)){
                array_push($datos, $entrada);
            }
        }
    }
}
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($datos, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
?>
```

Básicamente en el `PHP` lo que hago es comprobar los `IDs` de las entradas que tienen traducciones del idioma que le paso por el `WHERE`, mas tarde compruebo si esa variable aparece en la siguiente consulta para que, si tiene una traducción ya realizada, no aparezca. Como dije el `array` esta correctamente cuando lo imprimo.

Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Podrías mostrar la forma en cómo imprime el JSON

Answer (score 0):

gracias por contestar, te muestro como recibo el JSON

```
$.ajax({
            url: '<?=$ubicacionAjax;?>/ajax-consultarTraducciones.php',
            dataType: 'json', 
            type: 'post' 
          }).done(function (data){


              $.each(data, function(index, entrada){


                 $("#select_entrada_principal").append('<option value="'+entrada.identrada+'">'+entrada.titulo+'</option>');



                });

           });
```